# Indy 10 error when try to install a new version in Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, installation, indy, indy10, delphi-xe3

I'm trying to install a new version of Indy 10 in Delphi XE3.

I'm using the `Fullc_XE3.bat` to compile the component, it works and finish OK, however, when I try to install `dclIndyCore170.bpl` I get the next popup error:

> Procedure entry point not found @Idstack@TIdStackLocalAddressList@GetAddress$qqri in the dynamic link library D:\Entorno XE3\COMPONENTES\Indy-master\C17\Win32\Release\dclIndyCore170.bpl

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I cleaned Delphi's Indy installation, deleting all indy files: dcp, dcu, pas, bpl.

Could you help me please?

[image: The error when I try to install the bpl]

Answer (score 2):

First off, if you are doing a *DELPHI* installation, you should NOT be using the `Fullc_XE3.bat` script at all. That script is meant only for a *C++BUILDER* installation instead (the `c` in the filename stands for C++).  For Delphi, simply open Indy's 5 `.dpk` packages (or the `Indy170.groupproj` project group) directly in the IDE and use the Project Manager's `Compile` and `Install` options.

Second, Delphi XE3 was released in September 2012, but `TIdStackLocalAddressList` was introduced in April 2013 for Indy 10.6.0 in XE4.  So, you have clearly NOT cleared out the old Indy version that shipped with XE3 before installing the new Indy version.  Your IDE is encountering an old binary that was left behind.